# How can I find the Start and End Dates under a Supervisor code in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to obtain the dates in which an employee is in a certain supervisor code. Some employees might have gaps in the their employment in which the switch from supervisor to non-supervisor. I am having trouble getting the date before the supervisor status changes (to capture the last date of a supervisor stint). Here is the table I am using.

| ID | Employee | Position_Title | Effective_Date | Supervisor_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-05 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-04 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-03 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-02 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-01 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2017-01-02 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2016-01-04 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2015-01-05 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2014-01-06 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Vice President | 2013-11-11 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Vice President | 2012-01-01 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2017-01-02 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2016-01-04 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2015-01-05 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2014-01-06 | Non-Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | President | 2018-01-02 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | President | 2016-02-11 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | President | 2015-09-03 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | Vice President | 2014-09-01 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | Staff | 2013-09-01 | Non-Supervisor |

Here is the output I am expecting:

| ID | Employee | Position_Title | Supervisor_Start | Supervisor_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-01 |  |
| 1234 | John Adams | Vice President | 2012-01-01 | 2014-01-05 |
| 1234 | Stacy Jones | President | 2014-09-01 |  |

Comment: Why is the vice president included? They are classed as a "Non-Supervisor".

Comment: Can you please describe how did you get these dates based on your sample data. It's unclear where, for example, 2010 came from because there's no any date of that year in the data. Adam Jones had never been a vice president with supervisor status. How did you decide to put blank or a date in `end` date? Also note that `1/2/2345` is confusing because it doesn't allow to guess the month position: the most recognizable format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Thank you both for pointing out these errors. I have edited the table.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY employee
  ORDER BY effective_date
  MEASURES
    FIRST(id) AS id,
    FIRST(position_title) AS position_title,
    FIRST(effective_date) AS supervisor_start,
    NEXT(effective_date) AS supervisor_end
  PATTERN (same_supervisor+)
  DEFINE
    same_supervisor AS
           FIRST(position_title) = position_title
       AND supervisor_status = 'Supervisor'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Employee, Position_Title, Effective_Date, Supervisor_Status) AS
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'President',      DATE '2020-05-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'President',      DATE '2020-04-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'President',      DATE '2020-03-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'President',      DATE '2020-02-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'President',      DATE '2020-01-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2017-02-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2016-04-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2015-05-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2014-06-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Vice President', DATE '2013-01-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Vice President', DATE '2012-01-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2017-02-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2016-04-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2015-05-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'John Adams',  'Staff',          DATE '2014-06-01', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'Stacy Jones', 'President',      DATE '2018-02-01', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'Stacy Jones', 'President',      DATE '2016-02-11', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'Stacy Jones', 'President',      DATE '2015-03-09', 'Supervisor' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'Stacy Jones', 'Staff',          DATE '2014-01-09', 'Non-Supervisor' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| EMPLOYEE | ID | POSITION_TITLE | SUPERVISOR_START | SUPERVISOR_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Adams | 1234 | Vice President | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |
| John Adams | 1234 | President | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* |
| Stacy Jones | 1234 | President | 2015-03-09 00:00:00 | *null* |

For `supervisor_end`, if you want the last date of the range, rather than the next date of the next range, then use `LAST(effective_date)` in place of `NEXT(effective_date)`.

Which would output:

| EMPLOYEE | ID | POSITION_TITLE | SUPERVISOR_START | SUPERVISOR_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Adams | 1234 | Vice President | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
| John Adams | 1234 | President | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 |
| Stacy Jones | 1234 | President | 2015-03-09 00:00:00 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4mMGiZz-)

Comment: I am getting an error - "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined". Thank you for your time!

Comment: @mattyh The code works in the fiddle linked in the answer. If it does not work for you then you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76039653/edit) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data that demonstrates the error you say occurs (because for my data it does work and does not give that error).